# log analyzing tool for analysing data for a time window

Tags: logging

I want to analyze log data for a specific time period, like calculating an average of a particular attribute in 10 seconds. There are services for doing this, but I haven't found a tool. Is there any tool which provides the same functionality as services like `loggly`, `splunk` or `logsense`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ELK (Elasticsearch, Logstash, Kibana) stack can be used for such. It does need some work to setup but it's definitely worth looking into it.

Comment: It is helpfull,does the watcher plugin helps in that case

Comment: That depends what you are looking for. The ecosystem has some moving parts. Watcher is mostly for alerting purposes. If you want to calculate a 10second avarage what you would need to do is define a logstash pipeline with the metrics plugin (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-metrics.html). Or you may also push the data as is to Elasticsearch and handle the aggregation to time periods in Kibana.

As I mentioned above it does need some work to setup a decent analyzing tool using the ELK stack but the power of the tools is right there at your finger tips :)

Comment: In addition to that,i want to compare analysis data with ,data extracted from database.Can i do this with jdbc?

Comment: Have a look at the following plugin: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-jdbc.html